# What is the most efficient way to transmit file over HTTP?

Tags: javascript, base64, filereader, binary-data

I writing a client which have to transmit files to a REST webservice.

I take the File object from the input control, then I use FileReader object to convert it in base64 (String). I noticed that the base64 string weight is 30-40% over the original file size. 
If I convert that string in binary size literally explodes, so I was wandering if there is a more efficient way to convert in string this file and send over HTTP.

```
function toBase64() {    
    var file    = document.querySelector('#base64').files[0];
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {               
            var bin = base64toBin(reader.result);
    var base64 = reader.result;
    console.log(bin, base64);
    });

    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}

function base64toBin(data) {
        var binArray = []
        var datEncode = "";

        for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
            binArray.push(data[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2)); 
        } 
        for (let j=0; j < binArray.length; j++) {
            var pad = padding_left(binArray[j], '0', 8);
            datEncode += pad + ' '; 
        }
        function padding_left(s, c, n) { if (! s || ! c || s.length >= n) {
            return s;
        }
        var max = (n - s.length)/c.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            s = c + s; } return s;
        }
        return binArray;
    }
```

Here is a poc:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93bne3bn/)

Comment: no need to handle this yourself. take a look at [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Comment: also note that there is already a function to make base64 to binary [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob)

Comment: @RolandStarke Nice advice, but it is not supported in Safari Mobile. Anyway, using formdata, file is encoded in base64?